# Activate cache for WFS service in deegree 3.4.x

Tags: cache, tomcat, deegree

We have a service WFS integrated in deegree for data harvesting. Currently we have a lot of data and the responses are very slow, more than a minute.

The used version of Deegree is 3.4.22, with Apache Tomcat 8.5.90 and OpenJDK8U-jdk_x64_windows_hotspot_8u282b08.
Is it possible to activate any kind of cache to improve response times?

Our data are very static.

Comment: Please provide more information about your setup. Which data source is used to serve data via the WFS interface? Which request is performing slowly?